# How to bypass this system error message?

Tags: support, posting

I want to copy and paste the jQuery code in this forum, but the forum system says:

> Your code appear to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button.

How to bypass this system error message so I can paste the code?

Comment: It says you have to indent your code using the Code Sample button (that's the one with `{}` on it), which IMO means you haven't.  So indent your sample and everything will be OK.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Select the code using mouse and press `Ctrl+k`.